# R2DBC repositpries do not work even for basic methods

Tags: project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I'm using Spring Boot, java 17 and Postgresql in my reactive web application. However even simplest methods like cardRepository.findAll(); return  ERROR c.a.a.c.h.ControllerExceptionHandler - executeMany; bad SQL grammar [SELECT card.* FROM card] exception.

These are my classes so far, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
@Configuration
public class PostgresConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
                PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .port(5432)
                        .username("postgres")
                        .password("0000")
                        .database("databaseName")
                        .codecRegistrar(EnumCodec.builder()
                                .withEnum("card_status", CardStatus.class)
                                .withEnum("credit_card_order_status", CreditCardOrderStatus.class)
                                .withEnum("credit_status", CreditStatus.class)
                                .withEnum("payment_system", PaymentSystem.class)
                                .build())
                        .build());
    }
}
```

```
public interface CardRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Card, UUID> {
}
```

```
    liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:db.migration/db.changelog-master.xml
        database-change-log-lock-table: LIQ_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
        database-change-log-table: LIQ_DATABASECHANGELOG
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        password: ${PSQL_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:0000}
        url: jdbc:postgresql://${PSQL_DATASOURCE_URL:localhost}:5432/databaseName
        user: ${PSQL_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:postgres}
    r2dbc:
        password: 0000
        url: r2dbc:postgresql://${PSQL_DATASOURCE_URL:localhost}:5432/databaseName
        username: postgres
```

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<Card>> getCreditCards() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(repo.findAll());
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "card")
public class Card {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column("card_number")
    private String cardNumber;

    @Column("holder_name")
    private String holderName;

    @Column("expiration_date")
    private LocalDate expirationDate;

    @Column("payment_system")
    private PaymentSystem paymentSystem;

    @Column("balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @Column("status")
    private CardStatus status;

    @Column("transaction_limit")
    private BigDecimal transactionLimit;

    @Column("delivery_point")
    private String deliveryPoint;

    @Column("digital_wallet")
    private Boolean digitalWallet;

    @Column("virtual")
    private Boolean virtual;

    @Column("co_brand")
    private String coBrand;

    @Column("hashed_pin_code")
    private String hashedPinCode;

    @Column( "card_name")
    private String cardName;

    @Transient
    private CardProductOrder cardProductOrder;

    @Column("card_product_order_id")
    private UUID cardProductOrderId;
 
    @Transient
    private Account account;

    @Column("account_id")
    private UUID accountId;
}
```